# SSH won't accept password anymore for one user only

Tags: server, ssh, password

SSH has worked for me for a long time, but no longer. I cannot access my host via a password (hosted locally)

in `etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
port 22222
```

I do not use pub keys, I have never used pub keys. I don't have pub keys on either my host or client.

I have always connected with a password, and now I can't... here's what happens.

```
ssh -v 192.168.xxx.xx -p 22222 -l mother
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.xxx.xx [192.168.xxx.xx] port 22222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mother@192.168.xxx.xx's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
mother@192.168.xxx.xx's password:
```

It won't take my password
rebooting
logging out and back in
faillock --reset --user mother
changing the password from root

I can sign in normally fine
But whether its locally or from another pc i cannot ssh in, it denies my password.

I CAN sign into root from ssh
I cannot sign into my user

Note: I have no firewall installed or running

Comment: Check the permission of $HOMEDIR for this account. Check /var/log/syslog after tried logon.

Comment: I'd check `/var/log/auth.log`.  My first guess is the `sshd_config` has `AllowGroups ssh` and the *mother* user needs to be added to the *ssh* group: `adduser mother ssh`